# Attempting to change marked date on calender in react native is resulting in a syntax error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, calendar

```
<Calendar 
   markedDates={{`${this.state.currentDate}%`: {selected: true, marked: false, selectedColor: '#ff7f00'},}}
   onDayPress={(day) => this.manageGroups(day)}
/>
```

I am trying to set the marked date on the calender to the currentDate state. however, doing it this way is yielding in a syntax error. How can I solve this? I have provided the link to the source of where I got my calender from.

https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars

Answer (score 0):

Setting state in ReactJS can be done in 2 ways:

1. `this.setState()` function, used in stateful components (which means components built with `class ComponentName extends React.Component`), you can read more in the React docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).
2. through the `useState` hook in stateless components (which means components which are pure functions, built with `const ComponentName = () => {}`, you can read more about the state hook in the React docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate).

What you added in your code snippet is a way to **read** the state. However you have a `%` symbol at the end of the state declaration, which is unnecessary and that's probably what's causing your syntax error.